# Copy primary key column data into other column of same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can anyone help me to copy primary key column data into another column of same table?

Example: **Student** table

```
ID PK
Name
age
IID
```

I want to check if `IID` column is null, then I want it to update with primary key column value of the same table, and looking for some generic way to do this as we have this kind of requirement for multiple tables.

We have other table like this

**Dep**

```
DID PK
DNAME
IID
```

I'm trying but no table to find appropriate way to do this.

Comment: Make the other “fake ID” column a Computed Column, let the expression be value of the PK (or some other derivation function, using the PK and possible “override” column). Triggers are even more of a PITA.

Comment: `update table set IID = ID where IID is null`?

Comment: we sometimes for other tables even Column names which are primary should be found so its becoming problem while selecting Primary key column to plce in update statement

Answer (score 1):

Create a stored procedure like the one shown below and pass table name, primary key column name & copy to column name to it. It will create query and execute.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateColumnValue]
    @tableName as varchar(100),
    @copyFromColumnName as varchar(100),
    @copyToColumnName as varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @query as varchar(max);

    SET @query = ' UPDATE ' + @tableName + 
                 ' SET ' + @copyToColumnName + ' = ' + @copyFromColumnName +
                 ' WHERE ' + @copyToColumnName + ' IS NULL';

    EXECUTE(@query);

END
```

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: @marc_s thanks for this information. I will keep this in mind. Its really helpful information.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `Foreign Key` References to the Same Table:

```
CREATE TABLE  DEPT (
ID INT Primary Key,
Name VARCHAR(50),
age INT ,
IID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES DEPT(ID))
```

By using `UPDATE` Statement:

```
UPDATE DEPT
SET IID=ID
WHERE IID IS NULL
```

Comment: No sir we cannot do this as 
we are looking for something like we wish to update all existing rows with ID value if IID column is not having any value